# Usage of 'I' and 'Me'

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

Is there any rule as to what is used in the beginning of a sentence, 'I' or 'Me'?

Example: 1) I and x are good friends.
         2) Me and x are good friends.

Which is correct? Or are both of these correct?

Comment: Use "I" in the **subject** of the sentence.  Use **me** as a direct object, or the object of a preposition.  In English, sentences usually begin with the subject ... but not always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you always put others before yourself.

So, **"I and x"** and **"Me and x"** are definitely wrong.

---

Now let's talk about [pronouns](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/pronouns).

- [Pronouns](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/pronouns) are used in place of a noun that has already been mentioned or that is already known, often to avoid repeating the noun.

*That means, when you talked about your friend, which his name is Onyetenyevwe, and you would avoid saying his name since his name was very long.* ***This is where [pronouns](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/pronouns) come in.***

- **"I"** is a ***subjective pronoun***, it must act as a **subject** in sentences.
- **"Me"** is an ***objective pronoun*** of **"I"**, it must act as an **object** in sentences.

---

---

Your question is what should be in the blank.

> - ______________ are good friends.
>
> 1) I and x
>
> 2) Me and x
>
> > **Both are wrong**.
> >
> > 1) is wrong because **"I"** comes before **"x"**
> >
> > 2) is wrong because **"Me"** acts as subject for the sentence, and comes before **"x"**.

*The right answer for the question is* **"X and I"**.

***`X and I are good friends.`***

Answer (score 0):

I would write, "X and I are good friends".

1. While "x and me" sounds ok in oral English, "I" is the way to go, especially in written English.
2. Etiquette demands putting others before oneself so it should not be "I and X"